# HttpSessionBindingListener and HttpSessionListener

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was using sessionDestroyed() method of HttpSessionListener to get the current session object but it was not possible as session already get destroyed before execution of sessionDestroyed(). Then I tried to get the same using valueUnbound() of HttpSessionBindingListener but still I am unable to get the current session object. In case if I want this object, how to implement the same.

Comment: What you are getting when you do `event.getSession()` ?

Answer (score 1):

What servlet version are you using? 2.3? If this is the case on page 21 of the servlet 2.4 
specification has a note about compatibility with version 2.3 of the servlet:

"SRV.1.6.1 HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed
In the previous versions of the specification, this method was defined as:
Noti?cation that a session was invalidated.
As of Version 2.4, this method is changed to:
so that it notifies *before* the session invalidation. If the code assumed the previous behavior, it must be modified to match the new behavior."

In this case, try changing the declaration in web.xml to version 2.4+ and check your libraries You can see more details in specifications serlvet 2.3 and 2.4